# How can I get an XML fragment as a string from an XElement?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an `XElement` and inside that element I have another XML fragment.  How do I retrieve the XML?

If I try the following, I get only the value:

```
string str = "<Root><Node1>value1</Node1><Node2></Node2></Root>";

XElement elem = XElement.Parse(str);
string innerXml = elem.value;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eric White just posted a blog article to do exactly that - convert XElement to XmlNode and back.

Check it out [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericwhite/archive/2008/12/22/convert-xelement-to-xmlnode-and-convert-xmlnode-to-xelement.aspx).

Marc

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var x = elem.Descendants();
```

This will return you all the descendants of the root node - if you want a specific one you can pass its name as a string parameter to this same method.

**Edit:** If you *really* need it as a string you can aggregate the nodes.  Here is an extension method that will do the trick:

```
public static String InnerXml(this XElement source)
{
    return source.Descendants().Select(x => x.ToString()).Aggregate(String.Concat);
}
```

Comment: that gives the XML including Root, but i want the innerXml

Comment: i dont think that will work, because that will return me a enumeration of all the descendants, i will have the add the each element to get the innerXml

Answer (score 0):

I just going to create an extension method InnerXml to return me the innerXML